# configuring internet in ubuntu12.10 Lenovo G580

Tags: internet

I have bought Lenovo G580 and wanted to install Ubuntu 12.10. I have no previous experience with Ubuntu. I have installed it using Windows installer, but internet connection was not detected.
Please suggest what to be done after installation (like any settings, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest wire connection for your first time. Generally it works if you just connect cable. Otherwise you have to configure your wire connection from the connection icon on the top. Then you have to go connection manager and modify IPv4 settings with your router's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As thanassis noted, a wired connection is the easiest to set up initially. If you *must* use wifi, it might be helpful to use the Windows Wireless Drivers (ndisgtk) tool to aid in downloading wireless drivers.

```
sudo apt-get install ndisgtk
```